# Deleting the first list item if it contains a specified number of items

Tags: jquery

I am practicing the imitation of a bash console, I am practically at the very end, although there is a problem. I need to always delete the first element of the .bash-line class if the total number of elements exceeds the given value.

I have created a function for this, unfortunately - it removes the first element, but does not add the next one. What can I do to change that?

```js
function animateConsole(string) {

  var bash = $('<p class="bash-line"></p>');
  
  $("#console-content").append(bash);
    var typed = new Typed(bash.get(0), {
      strings: [string],
      typeSpeed: 10,
      showCursor: false,
  }); 
  
}

function deleteFirst() {
  
  if($('.bash-line').length == 2) {
  
    $(".bash-line").each(function() {
      $(this).first().remove();
    });
    
  }
  
}

$(document).ready(function() {

  setTimeout(function() {animateConsole('<span>//</span>GET CONNECTION SECRET');}, 1000);
  setTimeout(function() {animateConsole('<span>//</span>SENDING REQUEST'); deleteFirst();}, 2000);
  setTimeout(function() {animateConsole('<span>//</span>WAITING FOR RESPONSE');}, 3000);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/typed.js@2.0.6/lib/typed.min.js"></script>

<div id="console-content">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to foreach on every found elements to remove the first element of a set of jQuery elements, just do:

$("#console-content p.bash-line").first().remove();

You can also check the jquery *first* method documentation: https://api.jquery.com/first/

Here's the full working example:

```js
function animateConsole(string) {
    var bash = $('<p class="bash-line"></p>');

    $("#console-content").append(bash);

    deleteFirst();
    var typed = new Typed(bash.get(0), {
        strings: [string],
        typeSpeed: 10,
        showCursor: false,
    });
}

function deleteFirst() {
    if($('.bash-line').length > 2) {
        $("#console-content p.bash-line").first().remove();
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {animateConsole('<span>//</span>GET CONNECTION SECRET');}, 1000);
    setTimeout(function() {animateConsole('<span>//</span>SENDING REQUEST');}, 2000);
    setTimeout(function() {animateConsole('<span>//</span>WAITING FOR RESPONSE');}, 3000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/typed.js@2.0.6/lib/typed.min.js"></script>

<div id="console-content">
</div>
```

Comment: Did you really feel the need to add a duplicate answer to mine 20 minutes after it was posted?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is because you're looping through the `.bash-line` elements, and removing the first one in each iteration. The result of this is that you remove all the items.

To fix this, don't loop:

```js
function animateConsole(string) {
  var bash = $('<p class="bash-line"></p>');
  $("#console-content").append(bash);
  var typed = new Typed(bash.get(0), {
    strings: [string],
    typeSpeed: 10,
    showCursor: false,
  });
}

function deleteFirst() {
  if ($('.bash-line').length == 2) {
    $(".bash-line:first").remove();
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    animateConsole('<span>//</span>GET CONNECTION SECRET');
  }, 1000);
  setTimeout(function() {
    animateConsole('<span>//</span>SENDING REQUEST');
    deleteFirst();
  }, 2000);
  setTimeout(function() {
    animateConsole('<span>//</span>WAITING FOR RESPONSE');
  }, 3000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/typed.js@2.0.6/lib/typed.min.js"></script>

<div id="console-content"></div>
```